# Python Django - models.Model subclass's constructor

Tags: python, django

I just started to learn Django and relatively new to Python.

I'm trying to understand Django's overview [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/overview/#django-at-a-glance)

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.full_name

class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.headline
```

I wonder how could they do something like this:

```
# Create a new Reporter.
>>> r = Reporter(full_name='John Smith')
```

and

```
>>> a = Article(pub_date=date.today(), headline='Django is cool',
...     content='Yeah.', reporter=r)
```

Can somebody point out where are the constructors defined in the example classes above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python classes don't need explicit constructors. However, in this case they are constructed by the metaclass, django.db.models.base.BaseModel, which they inherit from models.Model.